# Django Model Optimization

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

```
Class Model(models.Model):
   .......
   .......
   .......
   .......
   first_name = models.CHarField(max_length = 50)
   last_name = models.CharField(ma_lenghth = 50)

   def full_name():
      return '%s %s' %(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

- Calling `Models.objects.get().full_name()`  would be efficient

or

- `Model.objects.filter().values('first_name, 'last_name')` and than
  adding the string later would be better.

The question is in regards to database optimization. Basically I want to know if calling a method of a model loads the whole object or not. If not than I feel both would result in same database operations but if it loads the whole object than values method would be better optimization.

Please reply. Share any experiences if you have on this topic and also any statistics for the comparison if you have one.
Please note that this is an example and not the actual use case, the model also contains many other fields.

Few will feel that using `defer()` or `only()` will also give the desired result. But what I found in django documentation is that it basically only prevents those fields data from being converted to python object and not in sql look-ups. Therefore I don't think that's any better.
Please help me out
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not whether "calling a method of model loads the whole object or not", because that's irrelevant. The "loading of the whole object" has already been done by the `get` call. The method will operate on the model object returned by that call, which unless you specify otherwise (using for example `defer` or `only`) will be the entire object.

Comment: So will using defer or only be same as to using values?? Django docs specifies that there is a slight overhead in constructing a model with deferred fields. What I am not fully able to understand is that How much is the overhead and if its better to use the values thing.

Comment: No, `defer`/`only` give you an actual model instance, on which you can call your methods, but with some of the fields missing. `values` gives you a dictionary, not an instance, so you can't call your method on it. At this point though I can't help feeling that you're over-optimising: have you checked that this is actually a bottleneck?

Comment: So are you saying calling model.objects.only('first_name', 'last_name').get().full_name() will be the same as the calling the values method. But I seriously doubt it as this only method is to prevent conversion from sql to python objects rather than look up in the sql level. So I think it might not be that faster.

Comment: Its not over optimising actually coz my queries normally need to return few fields rather than all the fields so I find quering for the whole object might not be a good idea. And if you can help let me know any tool I can use to check the queries actually being run in the sql to find the speed and all.

Comment: My app doesn't serve templates it only generates json responses for the front-end. Therefore I am not able to use it. Is there any other tool to only look at the sql-part.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `get` or `filter` and then access to the object or objects from those querisets, you don't get extra queries if and only if you use the fields of the model you are accessing. For example, in your case those fields would be `first_name` and `last_name`.

But it is different in case you have a foreign key to other model. When you try to access to fields of that model, the simple query you made before doesn't get from the database the other object. So when you try to access it, you will access another time to your database. To solve this problem, you should see the documentation of [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) and [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

Hope it helps!